# Requesting information about Norway roads

Tags: planning, bicycles, norway

I'm planning to cycle up mountains which I can ski in March.
Now, I'm searching for the roads free from snow in March.

Could you please give me information about roads in Norway or introduce sites that show road conditions in March?

Comment: Norway is a big place, spanning a big range of latitudes. You need to be much more specific than just "roads in Norway".

Comment: @DavidRicherby Although that is true, cycling up high enough on a mountain so one can ski is going to mean snowy roads anywhere in Norway.

Answer (score 5):

Roads in mountainous areas in Norway will not be free from snow in March.  Snow will get cleared from most public roads, but a layer of packed snow and ice will remain.

Get some studded tyres for your bike and be prepared to ride on roads that may be icy or covered in packed snow.